# deleting the contents of a character array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have initialized a character array as:
char Buffer[1000]={0};
In this array, data is received from a socket and displayed
Everytime I display the contents of this array, I want to again initilize all its contents to zero. If I don't do that and again read data from the socket using the same array, some old data present in array is also displayed.
i used memset() function to again initialize all contents of array with zeros before receiving the data second time, but it didn't work.
Is there any other way of doing that in c/c++ ?
seeking help :(

Comment: "i used memset() function to again initialize all contents of array with zeros before receiving the data second time, but it didn't work" what didn't work?

Comment: it seems you mix up memset parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contract for `recvfrom` doesn't guarantee what happens to the memory in between the end of the message received and the end of the buffer.  That's why `recvfrom` returns the number of *valid* bytes.  **The remainder of the buffer is not unchanged, it is overwritten with trash.**

Change

```
memset(receiveBuffer,'\0',1000); 
recv_len = recvfrom(socketIdentifier, receiveBuffer, sizeof(receiveBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientSocket, &clientSocketLength);
```

to

```
recv_len = recvfrom(socketIdentifier, receiveBuffer, sizeof(receiveBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientSocket, &clientSocketLength);
if (recv_len > 0)
    memset(receiveBuffer + recv_len, 0, 1000 - recv_len);
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)
I tried it and the whole problem is solved :) You people are amazingly Genius :)
Thanks a lot everyone:)

Answer (score 0):

After the data is being received and displayed, run a loop from 0 to 999 to reset the contents of the array.

Comment: `void receiveAtSocket()
{ 
 receiveBuffer[]={0};
   memset(receiveBuffer,'\0',1000);
   if((recv_len = recvfrom(socketIdentifier, receiveBuffer, sizeof(receiveBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientSocket, &clientSocketLength)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
      {
         MessageBox(NULL,
       "ERROR",
       "Could not Receive Data",
       MB_ICONINFORMATION);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
   PostMessage(AH_Glb_windowHandle, WM_thread,0, 0);
}`

Comment: that is exactly what `memset` does, only `memset` is much faster

Comment: when i use memseet in my code, no data is displayed, but when I remove it, the data is displayed. That's why I thought memset() is not suitable  :(

Comment: I think I was using it the wrong way. it turned out to be working now :)

Comment: I may sound stupid now but can you explain what does the followingline mean?
memset(receiveBuffer + recv_len, 0, 1000 - recv_len); 
I tried it and the issue is solved yet I don't know how it happened :p

Comment: the code worked but I am a little confused that since I am using memset before displaying the buffer, then it must reset the entire buffer but how does it displays the buffer correctly?

Comment: @AyeshaHassan: It resets the end of the buffer, everything past the first `recv_len` bytes which are valid.